# Spring Boot One to Many Issue in Intellij

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, hazelcast

I have a problem about showing genre list when I get all values from getAllMovie function after I create a movie object.

While I can see a director's name, I cannot see any information about genres.

If the problem comes from relation mappping or anywhere , How can I fix it?

Here is the project Link : [Project Link](https://github.com/Rapter1990/springboothazelcast)

Here is my Movie class.

```
public class Movie implements Serializable {

@OneToMany(mappedBy="movie",cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<Genre> genres = new HashSet<>();

@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn
private Director director;
}
```

Here is Director class.

```
public class Director implements Serializable {

@OneToMany(mappedBy="director",cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<Movie> movies;

}
```

Here is Genre Class.

```
public class Genre implements Serializable {

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn
private Movie movie;

}
```

Here is my updateMovie test Function

```
@Test
    void updateMovieById() throws ParseException {

        createMovie();

        Long id = 1L;
        Movie movie = movieService.findById(id).get();

        movie.setName("Movie B");
        movie.setRating(7.5);

        Director movieDirector = new Director();
        movieDirector.setName("Director 2");
        movie.setDirector(movieDirector);

        LocalDate now = Utils.formatDate(LocalDate.of(2019, Month.JANUARY, 1));
        movie.setCreatedAt(now);

        Genre genreFirst = new Genre();
        genreFirst.setName("Historical");
        genreFirst.setMovie(movie);

        Genre genreSecond = new Genre();
        genreSecond.setName("Horror");
        genreSecond.setMovie(movie);

        Set<Genre> genres = new HashSet<>();
        genres.add(genreFirst);
        genres.add(genreSecond);

        movie.setGenres(genres);

        Movie updatedMovie = movieService.update(id,movie);


        assertThat(updatedMovie.getId()).isGreaterThan(0);
    }
```

Here is my getAllMovies function.

```
@Test
void getAllMovies() throws ParseException {

   createMovie();

   List<Movie> movieList =  movieService.findAll();

   assertThat(movieList.size()).isGreaterThan(0);
}
```

Comment: You don't set the `Movie` on the `Genre`, you should also add the `Movie` to the `Director`. You have bi-directional relations so you must set both ends.

Comment: @M.Deinum How can I set the movie to Genre and Director. Is it possible to write these codes if you don't mind?

Comment: `genre.setMovie(movie)`. I assume you have the appropriate setters. However ideally you should have adder methods (`addMovie` on `Director` and `addGenre` on the `Movie`) which does that, next to adding it to the lest. You should remove your `setGenres` method as that is potentially dangerous (when used on a managed entity, you basically destroy the managed collection, leading to fun to debug errors).

Comment: @M.Deinum I updated my test function. Is it right?  As I define movies as a Set in Director. How can I set it to movie?

Comment: As stated, you should be using adders instead of setting it directly.

Comment: @M.Deinum I updated my test function. How can I define add method? . I have no idea how to write it. Is it possible to show me this method? Can you look through the link which is directed to this sample sample?

Comment: `public void addMovie(Movie movie) { this.movies.add(movie); movie.setGenre(this);}` something along those lines. See also https://vladmihalcea.com/jpa-hibernate-synchronize-bidirectional-entity-associations/ for a more in-depth explanation.

Comment: I defined `public void addGenre(Genre genre) { this.genres.add(genre); }` in Movie and `public void addMovie(Movie movie) {
        this.movies.add(movie);
    }` in Director. Is it right? How can I define createMovie and updateMovie in test?

Comment: Just call those methods.

Comment: @M.Deinum When I update movie, genres cannot be updated.  Updated values are set as a new value. That's why I got 4 genres. How can I fix it?

Comment: Did you implement a correct equals and hashcode? That is important for JPA entities as well.

Comment: I added `@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = "genres")` in Movie and `@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = "movies")` in Director. I also updated my github repository.

Comment: Don't, please don't... Write your own equals and hashcode. Using the Lombok generated one is a bad idea for JPA!.

Comment: I wrote a my own equals and hashcode methods for all entities but I cannot handle with the issue in test part? I also updated my github repository. Can you look through it?

Comment: @M.Deinum I did what you said. I cannot solve the issue? I only can add one genre.

Comment: @M.Deinum I updated my repository. Can you look through it if you don't mind?